# C2HS marshalling double pointer

Tags: haskell, c2hs

When there is a function like:

```
some_type_t* some_type_create(const char* name, char** errptr);
```

is there a way to get C2HS to generate a Haskell binding with the following signature?

```
someTypeCreate :: String -> IO (SomeTypeFPtr, String)
```

Here is what I can get so far:

```
{#fun some_type_create as ^ 
    {`String', alloca- `Ptr CChar' peek*} -> `SomeTypeFPtr' #}
```

and it works in a way that I get

```
someTypeCreate :: String -> IO (SomeTypeFPtr, (Ptr CChar))
```

but how do I make it return `IO (SomeTypeFPtr, String)`
(or better `IO (Either String SomeTypeFPtr))` since `String` represents the error)?

I assume that I should use/write a different marshaller to use instead of `peek` which would convert the result type but I don't quite understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured it out, I just wrote the following marshallers:

```
nullableM :: (Ptr a -> IO b) -> Ptr a -> IO (Maybe b)
nullableM f ptr = if ptr == nullPtr
    then return Nothing
    else liftM Just $ f ptr
{-# INLINE nullableM #-}

toStringMaybe :: CString -> IO (Maybe String)
toStringMaybe = nullableM peekCString 
{-# INLINE toStringMaybe #-}

peekStringMaybe :: Ptr CString -> IO (Maybe String)
peekStringMaybe x = peek x >>= toStringMaybe
{-# INLINE peekStringMaybe #-}
```